# Can Android phones/tablets access W-Fi network drives?

Tags: wi-fi

There are many WLAN routers currently available which have a USB port to connect external HDDs. These are than easily available on Windows machines directly in Windows Explorer, they look like common network drives.

If I used an Android-based smartphone or a tablet which support WLAN, would it be possible to access these network drives somehow? I'm entertaining the idea of getting a tablet, and it's important to know if I can access a larger storage than what would be available locally via an SD card (if such a slot even would be present on a particular specimen).

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of these routers mount your drive as a network samba share (like windows file sharing), which android phones can access with apps, like ESFilexplorer or AndSMB. They can stream off it or download files to SD card.

Answer (score 0):

I used [ES File Explorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) on Android phone to access a hard disk attached to a Wi-Fi router and it was able to play content directly without copying to my phone.

Comment: Can you please add details as to how you achieved this?